# ajax Address field for email client-like environment (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, components

There is this magical To-Address field in yahoo mail , which you can type-in the names and shows you an auto-complete list , click on the names and then a block shows up in the field , each block has a tiny x mark and you can just delete the names from the field and all remaining block shift to left to fill it's place !

how can i achieve this behavior for a address field in my application , with minimal effort on asp.net ?

plus : i mainly looking for a .net component which is preferably free to use , the commercial one's are appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a .NET component, take a look at some client side plugins.  TagIt, for JQuery, is a good one for doing just what you are talking about doing.  Here is a demo: http://webspirited.com/tagit/

You can also wire up a web service and retrieve values from the server based on the input the user has entered (auto complete functionality).  It's definitely one close to what you are referring to.